# Missing characters after converting bytes to ascii then string

Tags: c#, ascii

This program opens a hidden folder through a given password. If you running this program for the first time, the user should enter 'new' to create an account that holds his password and directory path, then, when he run it again and enter his password, the directory will open on file explorer. My problem is that when I 'inputs' and I try to open it through my program, a random directory is open.

**What's happening:** 
**Input:** C:\Users\joao_.DESKTOP-QMLOLSI\Desktop\League of Legends
**Output:** C:\Users

**What should happen:** 
**Input:** C:\Users\joao_.DESKTOP-QMLOLSI\Desktop\League of Legends
**Output:** C:\Users\joao_.DESKTOP-QMLOLSI\Desktop\League of Legends

My code: https://pastebin.com/qHeygbjM 
**Input:** lines 18~23
**Output:** line 71

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void createAcc() //method to create a account
        {
            string[] a = new string[2];
            Console.Write("Digite uma nova senha(password): ");
            a[0] = Console.ReadLine();//user's password
            Console.Write("Entre com o caminho escondido(folder path): ");
            string s = Console.ReadLine(); user's path
            Console.Write(s);
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);// converting to bytes, so I can 'encrypt' the path
            long result = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0);
            a[1] = result.ToString();
            File.WriteAllLines("MyFile.txt", a); //hold the data in a txt file
            Console.Write("Conta criada com sucesso. Feche e abra novamente e insira sua senha.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static bool checkPassword(string input)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] linesI = File.ReadAllLines("MyFile.txt");
                if (linesI[0] == input)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("Senha errada(Wrong password)");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.Write("Arquivo 'MyFiles.txt' não existe ou conta não criada. Fecha e abra novamente.");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return false;
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string a;
            Console.WriteLine("Senha(digite new para criar uma nova conta(new to a new account)):");
            a = Console.ReadLine();
            if (a == "new")
            {
                createAcc();
            }
            else
            if (checkPassword(a))
            {
                //    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(a);
                //int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
                //string[] linesI = File.ReadAllLines("MyFile.txt");
                //linesI[1] = i.ToString();
                //File.WriteAllLines("MyFile.txt", linesI);
                string[] linesO = File.ReadAllLines("MyFile.txt"); 
                long output = Convert.ToInt64(linesO[1]);
                byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(output);
                string s2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
                Console.Write(s2);
                Console.ReadKey();
                Process.Start("explorer.exe", s2); //if the password is right, the path should open, but it doesnt
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific which part of your code exhibits the problem? Don't just tell the line numbers, but for example mark the mark the relevant code lines with with comments that are easy and quick to see.

Comment: Please narrow down the code, make an [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: However, what on earth are you doing? It seems you're converting a string to a int64 value (8 bytes), writing this as a number to a file, then reading that number back in and converting it to bytes, then to a string. What do you expect to happen here? A long/int64 can only hold 8 bytes, which is `C:\Users` (8 characters). Please step back and try to explain what you want to do instead of asking for help with your current code. If you really want to know why your current code lost the rest of the string I can write up an answer but it is highly doubtful it is going to help you.

Comment: Also, this will be a good practice for you: Go through your code, and for every code line -- especially those where your code is calling methods, try explaining what it does. Double-check the MSDN documentation of these methods whether your assumptions are correct...

Comment: In line 21 you are converting 56 bytes into 8 bytes which seems to be the error. Instead why don't you simply save the byte array or the string itself? `long result = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0);`

Comment: English is not my first language. I will try to explain my problem more deeply.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen write a awnser, please, I will try understand

Comment: @masterjohn12 Converting to bytes isn't really encrypting the path. Nonetheless if you still have to do it, you cannot convert a 56-byte array to an int64 (which has only 8 bytes). That is why you are getting a trimmed path `C:\Users`. Instead save the bytes directly to file. Or use a proper encryption mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Neverminds, I figured out a better way to encrypts the user's path.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void createAcc()
        {
            string[] a = new string[2];
            Console.Write("Digite uma nova senha(password): ");
            a[0] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Entre com o caminho escondido(folder path): ");
            string s = Console.ReadLine();
            a[1] = encryptsOrDecrypts(s,'e');
            File.WriteAllLines("MyFile.txt", a);
            Console.Write("Conta criada com sucesso. Feche e abra novamente e insira sua senha.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static string encryptsOrDecrypts(string a, char mode)
        {
            if (mode == 'e')
            {
                string encrypted = "";
                foreach (char s in a)
                {
                    encrypted += (Convert.ToInt32(s) + 1) + ",";

                }
                encrypted = encrypted.Remove(encrypted.Length - 1);
                return encrypted;
            }else{

                string decrypted = "";
                string[] str = a.Split(',');
                for(int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
                {
                    decrypted += (char)(Convert.ToInt32(str[i]) - 1);

                }
                return decrypted;
            }

        }
        static bool checkPassword(string input)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] linesI = File.ReadAllLines("MyFile.txt");
                if (linesI[0] == input)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("Senha errada(Wrong password)");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.Write("Arquivo 'MyFiles.txt' não existe ou conta não criada. Fecha e abra novamente.");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return false;
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string a;
            Console.WriteLine("Senha(digite new para criar uma nova conta(new to a new account)):");
            a = Console.ReadLine();
            if (a == "new")
            {
                createAcc();
            }
            else
            if (checkPassword(a))
            {

                //File.WriteAllLines("MyFile.txt", linesI);
                string[] linesO = File.ReadAllLines("MyFile.txt");
                string output = encryptsOrDecrypts(linesO[1], 'd'); 
                Console.ReadKey();
                Process.Start("explorer.exe", output);
            }
        }
    }
}
```